# Is there a way Mock IBM MQ for Logicapp for testing

Tags: ibm-mq, azure-logic-apps

We have requirement, as per design, third party systems will push XML\CSV messages to IBM MQ queues, and we using Azure logic app need to consume those messages and send to Event hub.

My question is

1. As we dont have MQ available yet, and I am not able to give details in Azure and using Azure queues. Is there anyway we can mock like we are using MQ.
2. Logic app once receive messages XML can it store to Data lake instead of pushing through Eventhub(as Event hub storing message in AVRO format)

Any suggestions please.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you download and install the developer version of IBM MQ?  See here: https://developer.ibm.com/articles/mq-downloads/

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Roger, you can install [the developer version of IBM MQ](https://developer.ibm.com/articles/mq-downloads/) to mock for Logic App testing.

Once the IBM MQ Queue is available, you can [Send message from an on premise IBM MQ to Azure Service Bus queue](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-azure/wiki/How-to-Send-message-from-an-on-premise-IBM-MQ-to-Azure-Service-Bus-queue) and also able to Transform and Validate XML for workflows in Logic Apps.

You can refer to [Connect to an IBM MQ server from a workflow in Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-mq?tabs=managed), [Transform XML for workflows in Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-transform) and [Validate XML for workflows in Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-xml-validation)